# Android : snackbar not working in fragment class

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I want to use snackbar in my app so I set below code for that

```
public class FragmentAddProperty extends Fragment
{
   RelativeLayout mRelative 
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1,
                container, false);
    mRelative = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_pro_city);
    Snackbar.make(mRelative, "No images.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/edt_pro_city"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f8f8f8"
android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sample_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_list"
            android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

As result I got following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
```

How can I solve this ?

All suggestion are appreciable

Comment: Snackbar.make(view, "No images.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: please put your xml code.

Comment: try `build -> clean` on the IDE and run it again

Answer (score 3):

You can use snackbar in Frgamnet.just use object of ViewGroup.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  Snackbar.make(container, "Please Check your Internet Connection",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 }
```

Comment: Did not work for me in a Fragment used with a ViewPager2 and TabLayout

Comment: @Sam
Hi! Did you figure out how to create Snackbar inside fragment inside viewPager2? I have same trouble

Answer (score 0):

In Snakebar, you have to pass view or parent layout view. So just replace your id with view and replace your code with this .

```
Snackbar.make(view, "No images.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: you'd better explain why problem of questioner exists,not just instead solution.

Comment: what would be the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, say your existing layout is a RelativeLayout you could add a CoordinatorLayout to relative layout as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then, make sure you pass the CoordinatorLayout as the first argument of the Snackbar.make() command.

```
final View viewPos = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout);    
Snackbar.make(viewPos, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_undo, showListener)
                            .show();
```

This will result in the Snackbar being shown at the bottom of the CoordinatorLayout provided to the make() function.

If you pass a View that is not a CoordinatorLayout the Snackbar will walk up the tree until it finds a CoordinatorLayout or the root of the layout.

Comment: no it is not. The method takes a `View` as first parameter. If they wanted to enforce the usage of `CoordinatorLayout`, they would be have used explicitly it as first parameter and not a generi `View`

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot on google to try to display the snackbar in android fragments, But it;s not happening because I need to add parent view as "CoordinatorLayout".

In CoordinatorLayout I used my entire layout structre and I gave the CoordinatorLayout as a parent view for snack bar.

like following:

=> In .xml file

=> Java class file

CoordinatorLayout parentLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

```
    private void showInternetAlert(){

    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(parentLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }
            });

    // Changing message text color
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

    // Changing action button text color
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

    snackbar.show();

}
```

It's working fine for me.

The issue got at in xml file we need to place parent view as "CoordinatorLayout"

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar wont work without `CordinatorLayout`, you need to to create your  `fragment_list.xml` like this one, or `Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.action, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);` will end whit `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why not? The documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) says it requires a `View`, not a `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: display Snackbar in RelativeLayout as root cause Exception in my case, replace relative layout whit cordinator fix the problem.